# Connection to SQL Server with Windows applicationb

Tags: c#

I developed a Windows based Application**(**C# and SQL Server 2005**)** in which I used a Connection Form which estabilish a connection between my application and SQL Server. I created a setup of my application. I installed it to Client Machine, after get installed I run the application first time, the Connection Form appears to estabilish a connection with SQL Server. I entered the required input for connection, the connection has estabilished. Whenever I closed the application the connection get totally closed. Now I have to reconnect with SQL Server to run the software once again.

My query is that, I want to connect my application with SQL Server only once untill it get uninstalled, by which I will not have to estabilish a connection repeatedly. The Connection Form should appear only once untill uninstallation.
Thanks in advance to help me.

Comment: You could try placing your code to perform the database operations within a [`using`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079098/the-c-sharp-using-statement-sql-and-sqlconnection) block, so that the connection will close only after the commands within have been executed.

Comment: I don think its a good idea to keep the connection open for such a long period of time.You are holding on to a resource most of the time doing nothing.

Comment: Guys, I don't think that's what he's asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Typically applications read their connection info from a config file.  What you might do is simply have the application store your connecting string info into a file once the user has entered it.

Then from that point forward, when the application starts read the connection string from your file.

An example of using a configuration file for your connection string is at: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/31314-sql-basics-in-c%23/

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you want to save the Connection String (not keep the connection open indefinitely) so you can use the Connection String on subsequent launches of your application without having to show the Connection Form each time the application starts.

There are a variety of considerations and ways to accomplish this. I would start by looking at the following MSDN Article which discusses [Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You may also want to consider reading the Connection String from the config file, attempting to authenticate, and if that fails, display the Connection Form so the user can provide different credentials or change the server \ database name in the event their environment has changed.

Comment: @ChrisLively Don't know about that! Having a few different resources to solve the same problem is never a bad thing!