# What if i don't close database connection in disconnected mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am doing windows forms application with connection to SQL Server (disconnected mode). Every action I handle in my application needs the connection. So I don't know where to close the connection.

I am asking what if i don't close the connection. I know that there is no runtime error that appears. But is there any other error that could appear?

Comment: "the connection", as in "just 1" ? Can you guarantee that you ever only use 1 connection? If so then you shouldn't have much of a problem. If, on the other hand, you create connections all willy-nilly and don't close/dispose of them, then you're invariably going to end up in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a risk that if you are using the same connection for each method, from a private field or `GetConnection()` method etc.; you could end up trying to read/write when the connection is still open.

This could then throw errors and you could end up in a whole heap of it, if using a live SQL database.

If you can, create a new instance of a connection in a `using` statement each time you want to access the DB.

Like this:

```
var connectionString = "YourConnectionStringToTheDB";
var queryString ="YourSQLQueryHere"; // FROM * IN tbl SELECT * etc...

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

This way it is closed and disposed of when the code runs outside of the `using` statement's scope.

Notice that the SqlCommand is also in a `using` statement, as it too can be disposed of.

This is cleaner code and marks the objects for disposal by the Garbage Collector. (Google is your friend) - BIG topic; a lot of stuff to read.

Here is a similar question which gives you some more detail: [The C# using statement, SQL, and SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079098/the-c-sharp-using-statement-sql-and-sqlconnection)

**EDIT**

Better still, you could wrap your SQL code in a `try { }` `catch { }` block to handle any errors at runtime.

Comment: As another note, I would even wrap your `SqlCommand` in a using as well, as this also implements `IDisposable`