# ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReader and SqlDataAdapter insert query 3 times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
public static class db
{
    public static string databaseName = "blue_pumpkin";

    public static Temp query(string qr)
    {
        var s = new Temp();
        s.query(qr);
        return s;
    }
}

public class Con
{
    static SqlConnection sc = null;

    public static SqlConnection connect()
    {
        if (sc == null)
        {
            sc = new SqlConnection("server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=" + db.databaseName + ";Integrated Security=True;");
        }

        return sc;
    }
}

public class Temp
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    private string sqlQuery = "";
    private DataTable dataset = new DataTable();

    public long last_insert_id = -1;
    public int rows_affected = -1;
    public int num_rows = 0;
    public int num_columns = 0;
    public Boolean hasRows = false;

    public void query(string qr)
    {
        this.sqlQuery = qr;
        this.con = Con.connect();
        this.con.Open();

        SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(this.sqlQuery, this.con);

        try {
            this.rows_affected = cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.rows_affected = -1;
        }

        SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();
        this.hasRows = reader.HasRows;
        reader.Close();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cd);
        sda.Fill(this.dataset);

        this.num_rows = this.dataset.Rows.Count;
        this.num_columns = this.dataset.Columns.Count;

        string sql = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, this.con);

        try {
            this.last_insert_id = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.last_insert_id = -1;
        }

        this.con.Close();
    }

    public DataTable getDataTable()
    {
        return this.dataset;
    }
}
```

This is how I use it in every page where needed.

```
var b = db.query("SELECT * FROM [" + db.databaseName + "].[dbo].[registration] ");
Response.Write("Last id : " + b.last_insert_id.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("hasRows : " + b.hasRows.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("num_columns : " + b.num_columns.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("num_rows : " + b.num_rows.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("rows_affected : " + b.rows_affected.ToString() + "<br>");

var c = db.query("UPDATE  [" + db.databaseName + "].[dbo].[registration] SET reg_password = 'Pune'" +
"WHERE reg_id = 1; ");
Response.Write("Last id : " + c.last_insert_id.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("hasRows : " + c.hasRows.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("num_columns : " + c.num_columns.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("num_rows : " + c.num_rows.ToString() + "<br>");
Response.Write("rows_affected : " + c.rows_affected.ToString() + "<br>");

var queryString = "INSERT INTO [" + db.databaseName + "].[dbo].[registration] ([reg_name], [reg_age], [reg_gender], " +
   " [reg_creation_date], [reg_email], [reg_password], [reg_is_approved]) VALUES" +
   " ('"+ reg_name + "', '" + reg_age + "', '" + reg_gender + "', GETDATE(), '" + reg_email + "',"+
   " '" + reg_password + "', 0)";
db.query(queryString);

//OR 

DataTable dt = db.query("SELECT * FROM [" + db.databaseName + "].[dbo].[registration] WHERE [reg_id]=1").getDataTable();
```

Everything is working fine except when I run insert query it insert 3 times because of `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteReader` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

If I ran them separately, it works fine, but If I run them together, they insert it 3 times. Because I want to run all type of query in same function, is there any way possible to make it work all 3 simultaneously and insert query insert only one time and doesn't effect update or delete or different pattern query.

One thing I can think of is to create `insertQuery()` function separately just for insert data. But if anyone can give me a better Idea than I'm more than welcome.

Comment: Yes a better idea is to forget the idea to have one single method to execute all the possible interaction with a database.

Comment: By the way, you have a lot of problems here. Sql Injection is the worse one, correct parsing is another one. FInally failing to dispose correctly a connection is another big one. Please look at how to write a parameterized query and the basic concept of _disposable_ objects like the connection

Comment: can you provide me any link where I can learn and correct these mistakes? I'm from php and javascript background that's y I use a lot of var because I like it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079098/the-c-sharp-using-statement-sql-and-sqlconnection

Comment: You might also have a look at how to use stored procedures, rather than trying to build this up in C#. You've got a database engine there, not just a repository - use it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside your query method, these three lines are executing the insert statement.

```
    this.rows_affected = cd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();

    sda.Fill(this.dataset);
```

You need to separate these executions depending what you want to do, for example, if the statement isn't a select, only execute the **SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery** method, otherwise execute **SqlDataAdapter.Fill** method.

If you need to know if there is rows or the number of rows for the select statement, you can use the following code without using SQLDataReader

```
    SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cd);
    sda.Fill(dataTable); 
    Boolean hasRows = (dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0);
    Int32 noRows = (hasRows ? dataTable.Rows.Count : 0);
```

Hope it was usefull you!!